# Customer Logout event not triggering

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am using magento 2 + react (frontend).
I have setup grapql to interconnect with frontend-backend functionality

I have Customer Logout event in module which is not triggering,
i do not see any error in logs.

Any thoughts, if it need any correction ?
Thanks

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_logout">
        <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLogout" name="customer_logout_observer"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomerLogout.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Vendor\Module\Helper\Tracking;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomerLogout implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var Tracking
     */
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, Tracking $helper)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * Call helper & pass customer object
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customerlogout.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('CustomerLogout event');
            $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
            $this->helper->trackLogOut($customer);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score -1):

**You Use GraphQL Area. You have to put your events.xml file into app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/graphql**

**Please add your file at below:**

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/graphql**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_logout">
        <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLogout" name="customer_logout_observer"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***